# cron runs at wrong time

Tags: cron

I have a /etc/crontab file. It's pretty much the default one except for the daily tasks:

```
'# m h dom mon dow user  command  
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly  
00 2    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )  
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )  
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

So, I expect daily tasks to be executed ad 2:00 a.m. The problem is that they are executed at 7:30 a.m. (sometimes at 8:30 a.m.). I checked time zone settings and clock and everything is fine. What's wrong with the crontab file?

Comment: Your file, as quoted above, starts with a '. If that were a correct quote, your cron jobs would not run at all, so please check that.

Comment: "So, I expect daily tasks to be executed ad 2:00 a.m." your system is ON at 2am? If not ... anacron executes when you power up.

Comment: I inserted the ' just because if not the # is interpreted as a tag Jos. The file does not include it

Comment: Yes indeed Rinzwind. It's powered 24x7

Answer (score 1):

With you configuration the command `test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )` will in fact be executed at 2:00 AM, but the commands in `/etc/cron.daily` probably won't!

Lets look at the command more closely:

- The first command `test -x /usr/sbin/anacron` checks if the command `anacron` can be executed, it "fails" (returns 1) if `/usr/sbin/anacron` is not executable
- The `||` means: Execute the second command it the first one fails
- The second command `( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )` will execute all tasks in the directory `/etc/cron.daily`, without involving `anacron` in any way

In short: `cron` will only run the tasks in `/etc/cron.daily` if the command `/usr/sbin/anacron` is not available! `anacron` is an independent program that has its own heuristics for figuring out when to execute a task.

In order to let `cron` execute tasks at the times given in `/etc/crontab`, **just uninstall the `anacron` package**! Modifying the `/etc/crontab` command is not a good idea since the tasks in `/etc/cron.daily` would then be executed twice per day: Once by `cron` and once by `anacron`.

Comment: I got a little confused here alexander. Where are the heuristics of anacron defined? The job I´m interested runs just once (I know because uses logger and sends mail when starting and terminating)

Comment: The heuristics for anacron are defined in part in `/etc/anacrontab` (where you can set some basic settings), but the exact time when `anacron` will run can't be set. You can basically only tell it "run this command every day", but not "run this command every day at 2:00 AM". Whether you turn on your system on at 7:00 AM or 6:00 PM or leave it running until the next day, `anacron` will make sure that your command runs *at some point* during that day, but you can't tell it when that time is supposed to be.

Comment: Don't be confused that `/etc/crontab` contains entries for `anacron`: this file has nothing to do with `anacron` at all! As explained above the rules in `/etc/crontab` only apply if `anacron` is not installed. If you want exact control about when a task will run, just uninstall the `anacron` package then tweak the settings in `/etc/crontab` in what ever way you want. It is important to note however that if your system isn't turned on at 2:00 AM (or whatever you have set in your `/etc/crontab`) then `cron` will not run it until the next day.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I had this problem and found that anacron was taking over my planned crontab on always-on VPSes. Removing anacron completely resolved the problem.